# Programmatically change the src of an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

How can I change the `src` attribute of an `img` tag using javascript?

```
<img src="../template/edit.png" name="edit-save" alt="Edit" />
```

at first I have a default src which is "../template/edit.png" and I wanted to change it with "../template/save.png" onclick.

UPDATED:
here's my html onclick:

```
<a href="#" onclick="edit()"><img src="../template/edit.png" id="edit-save" alt="Edit" /></a>
```

and my JS

```
function edit()
{   
    var inputs = document.myform;
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
```

I've tried inserting this inside the edit(), it works but need to click the image twice

```
var edit_save = document.getElementById("edit-save");
    edit_save.onclick = function(){
       this.src = "../template/save.png";
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

its ok now

```
function edit()
{   
    var inputs = document.myform;
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = false;
    }

    var edit_save = document.getElementById("edit-save");

       edit_save.src = "../template/save.png";                              
}
```

Answer (score 420):

Give your img tag an id, then you can

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src="../template/save.png";
```

Comment: For simple things like setting the value of an input or changing an image src (**especial** when you're using elements that have IDs), you really should try to avoid jQuery, since the call is so much slower than the pure JS call

Comment: @william44isme and our page will be loaded slower than before. i think the jQuery is useful just for websites that uses a same code, very more. for example if we use the above code more than 30 or 50 times. so it's necessary to use jQuery

Answer (score 84):

You can use both jquery and javascript method:
if you have two images for example:

```
<img class="image1" src="image1.jpg" alt="image">
<img class="image2" src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
```

1)Jquery Method->

```
$(".image2").attr("src","image1.jpg");
```

2)Javascript Method->

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("image2");
image.src = "image1.jpg"
```

For this type of issue jquery is the simple one to use.

Comment: The poster never indicated any interest in a jQuery solution. Nor is the jQuery method simpler. Do not answer a JS questions with jQuery solutions (unless the post indicates they want that). It just confuses people trying to learn JS.

Comment: getElementByClassName returns collection of all elements. We need to mention index of the element too.  


    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("image2")[0];
    image.src = "image1.jpg"

Answer (score 40):

if you use the JQuery library use this instruction:

```
$("#imageID").attr('src', 'srcImage.jpg');
```

Comment: The question does not ask for a jQuery answer, include a jQuery tag, or suggest that it's okay to use jQuery.

Comment: Telling folks to use jQuery when an equivalent function is built right into Javascript makes no sense. Every JS question does not require a jQuery answer.  This solution is a kludge that prevents people from learning about what vanilla JS can already do.

Answer (score 14):

Give your image an id. Then you can do this in your javascript.

```
document.getElementById("blaah").src="blaah";
```

You can use this syntax to change the value of any attribute of any element.

Answer (score 9):

```
<img src="../template/edit.png" name="edit-save" onclick="this.src = '../template/save.png'" />
```

Comment: Inline JS isn't exactly a great idea.

Answer (score 8):

With the snippet you provided (and without making assumptions about the parents of the element) you could get a reference to the image with

```
document.querySelector('img[name="edit-save"]');
```

and change the src with

```
document.querySelector('img[name="edit-save"]').src = "..."
```

so you could achieve the desired effect with

```
var img = document.querySelector('img[name="edit-save"]');
img.onclick = function() {
    this.src = "..." // this is the reference to the image itself
};
```

otherwise, as other suggested, if you're in control of the code, it's better to assign an `id` to the image a get a reference with `getElementById` (since it's the fastest method to retrieve an element)

Answer (score 8):

In this case, as you want to change the `src` of the first value of your element, you have no need to build up a function. You can change this right in the element:

```
<a href='#' onclick='this.firstChild.src="../template/save.png"')'>
  <img src="../template/edit.png" id="edit-save"/>
</a>
```

You have several ways to do this. You can also create a function to automatize the process:

```
function changeSrc(p, t) { /* where p: Parent, t: ToSource */
  p.firstChild.src = t
}
```

Then  you can:

```
<a href='#' onclick='changeSrc(this, "../template/save.png");'>
  <img src="../template/edit.png" id="edit-save"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because you have a  tag like a parent of the  tag.
That why you have to click two time the images.

For me the solution is this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb