# how to change src value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id="3" class="dsi" onmousedown="test(3);" ondrop="checkImg('3');dropIt(event,3);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">

<img src="1.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event,4);" id="pic4" />
```

I want to change `src` value using javascript. There are nine dives and they already have 1 to 9 gif images. How can I add new `src` values leaving the rest of the things unchanged? (I mean `draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event,4);" id="pic4"`)

```
function ft1() {
            var imgSrcs = ['2.gif', '1.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif', '5.gif', '6.gif', '7.gif', '8.gif'];
            var myImages = [];
            for (var i = 0 ;i <=((imgSrcs.length)-1);i++) {
                var v = i;
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = imgSrcs[i];
                var div0 = document.getElementById(v+1);
                div0.appendChild(img);
                myImages[v+1] = img;
            }
```

Using this I can replace div images. But how can I remove first assigned src value and then replace new images?

Comment: if you use jQuery you can use the .attr() function. With .attr() you can set the value of attributes.
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but i can't use jquery

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/javascript-change-img-src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/javascript-change-img-src), simply do:

```
document.getElementById("pic4").src="...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.img').attr('src','http://source');
```