# Modify text.innerHTML to an image in show/hide script

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml

I recently got this simple script to show/hide several sections of an html page. I'm using it to show/hide the content of a div by clicking small "+" and "-":

```
    function toggle1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "+";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "-";
    }
}
```

Along with:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle1();" class="txt_side_table_cmd" id="displayText1><img src="imgs/up.gif" /></a>
<div id="toggleText1" style="display: block">Content here</div>
```

The code works fine but i'm trying to change the "+" and "-" text links to images links. I have very little knowlege of Javascript and I tried various modifications that made it worst. This original script in in an extrenal .js file.

Any ideas as how to change text links to image links ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400
you can find solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could make your image links in advance, then just append them to the element where the '+' and '-' were before:

```
var showControlImage = new Image(),
    hideControlImage = new Image();

showControlImage.src = "path/to/showImage.png";
hideControlImage.src = "path/to/hideImage.png";

// Then just use your toggle function with minor changes:
function toggle1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "";
        text.appendChild = showControlImage;
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "";
        text.appendChild = hideControlImage;
    }
}
```

Also, you should clean up your tag as per [Chandan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596487/2280630).

Answer (score 1):

Your id value is not close properly. Because of that `document.getElementById("displayText1")` is undefined. so try this

```
<a href="javascript:toggle1();" class="txt_side_table_cmd" id="displayText1">
```

instead of your

```
<a href="javascript:toggle1();" class="txt_side_table_cmd" id="displayText1>
```

Hope this helps...