# How do I use property in <img src="">?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image in my react class and want to achieve this:

```
<img src="images/status{this.props.status}.jpg"/>
```

How to do that?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
<img src={'images/status' + this.props.state + '.jpg'}/>
```

That was hell of a noob question :)

Comment: You could also make a variable before the rendering, like this: ```var img = 'images/status' + this.props.state + '.jpg';``` Then incject the var img into the src