# How to display an image through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jpeg, ionic-framework

I've asked this question already but I haven't been able to get many answers. I'll try and be more clear with this one!

I have an array which I am randomizing using math.random. I am displaying this array in the browser, each time the page refreshes it randomizes and outputs a different array item. Each array item contains a title and description which works, but I am also trying to add an image. I want this image to be displayed in the browser.

JavaScript:

```
var myArray = [
              {title: "my title", description: "my description", image: "file path"},
              ];

function getArray(ary){
  return ary[Math.floor(Math.random()*ary.length)];
}
var random = getArray(action);
```

and then in my HTML I have a `<script>` tag to display each portion of the item to the browser,

```
        document.write(random.title);
        document.write(random.description);
        document.write(random.image);
```

The problem is, the image doesn't show up it only displays the actual file path in text. How am I able to display the actual image?

Comment: Have you heard of the site google.com? It gives you answers even faster than stackoverflow.

Comment: how can someone learn about javascript before img src?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar I have tried Googling, I must not be that good at it...

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan trust me, I've tried img src... If you look at my previous question I asked, everyone was telling me to not use src in JavaScript... Maybe I misunderstood what they meant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to place the html for the image, this way:

```
document.write('<img src="'+random.image+'" width="203" height="350" />');
```

Otherwise your `random.image` only shows the output of the array, which is text with "file path" written in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've honestly spent hours on this and I don't know why I couldn't figure it out, but this made it all make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the images dinamically, a possible way is the following:

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "file.jpg");
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it valid HTML. Like `<img src="path">`

And this is some random text because the answer was too short.