# Dynamically change HTML element in android webView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I know this question is very common and can be solved using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag) - JS or JQuery and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) - how to run it on Android. Well this methods are working fine but when we call:

```
`myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('link1', 'link2')");`
```

image link1 is changing with link2, image is loading but page is restarted, so if I am at the end I am going to the beginning... can I just change link1 to link2 in real time, to not reload the page like in a real browser?

and I tried also setting id in my html file, like:

```
<img src="https://link1.jpg" id="dm5kode"/>
```

and run on Android:

`myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('dm5kode').src = 'link2'");`

here I don't get nothing just empty screen...

Comment: How did you fix this? could you get what you want. I have same problem

Comment: lok at @arun's answer - it's working

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not reload the page.

```
"javascript:(
         function()
         {
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('link1', 'link2')
         })()"
```

example:

```
   WebView wb;
    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web1.html");
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String uname = "email@mail.com";
            String pass = "******";
            /*
             * web.loadUrl(
             * "javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('email').value='"
             * + uname +
             * "';document.getElementById('pass').value='" +
             * pass + "';})()");
             */
            String link1 = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png";
            String link2 = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png";
            web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + link1+"', '" + link2+"')})()");
        }
    });
```

web1.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>dynamic Image</title>  
  </head>

  <body>

 <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" id="dm5kode"/>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Incredible! +1. Is there any reference for the hack?

Comment: Perfect answer, I wasted so much time until I found this! Thanks :)

Comment: btw, javascript can be also injected easily with 'webView.evaluateJavascript()' method. Example:

webView.evaluateJavascript("$('#my_div').remove();$('#another_div').remove();", null);