# how can I change path to img src from java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image in my div:

```
<div class="pressphone">
    <img class="phone" src="../img/template/iphone3.png">
</div>
```

how can I switch the photo to `../img/template/iphone4.png` from javascript/jquery?

Comment: have you had a look over here: [programmatically change the src of an img](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: Please try searching before asking questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("img.phone").attr("src", "../img/template/iphone4.png");
```

Note that this will replace the source of all images with class `phone`!

If that is an issue, you should consider to give your image a unique id and change the jquery selector accordingly.

Comment: $('img.phone').attr('src', '../url'); to be more specific