# javascript to show image and iframe between hrs

Tags: javascript

I need some help with a javascript

I need to create a script that checks a time range (costa rica time) and then displays the following:

1. a static image from 7pm to 5am
2. a  video streaming from 5.01am to 6.59pm

I prepared this solution but I don't know how to show the static image and the  streaming:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours(); //get the current local time's hour in military time (1..23)

//If the time is greater than or equal to 7pm or less than or equal to 7am
if (n >= 19 || n <= 5) 
{       
  show image
}
else 
{
   stream video
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery, You could do a one of two things (among others but these I find to be the simplest):

- Show and hide the Elements `$("videoselector").show();$("imageselector").show()`
- You could use .append() `$("body").append("<img src='src'/>")`

These both have js equivalents as well

- `document.getElementById("videoElementID").style.display = "none";`
- `document.createElement("IMG");`

Hope those help, please ask if you have any questions. I'll be happy to elaborate on any of these if needed.