# change src url from style tag using js

Tags: javascript

i am getting image url in style tag by default i want to replace src="#" with the image url in the style tag using js i dont know how to do this

```
 <img src="#" style="background:url('https://example.com/1.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;width:660px;height:330px;"class="demo-class">
```

final code is like

```
 <img src="https://example.com/1.jpg" style="background:url('https://example.com/1.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;width:660px;height:330px;"class="demo-class">
```

Comment: i think both are the same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to parse the current style of the element, get the URL out and update the `src` attribute.

To remove `style`, use:

```
img.removeAttribute('style');
```

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img'),
    // parse image URL and strip away url('')
    imgURL = img.style.backgroundImage.replace('url("','').replace('")','');
img.src = imgURL;

// remove style attribute afterwards.
img.removeAttribute('style');
```

```html
<img src="#" style="background:url('https://unsplash.it/400') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;width:660px;height:330px;"class="demo-class">
```

Comment: how do i remove style from <img> ?

Comment: i dont know why but this is not working on the site so i am doing this the
image is inside a div "single-post-thumb" so i want to take the image url in a variable and add a new image tag in that div with that image url and delete old image tag 

how do i take that image url in a var and delete the old img tag ?

$('.single-post-thumb').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')

Answer (score 0):

You can select `img` tags by class name like below and change `src` property:

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('demo-class')
var img = imgs[0];
img.src = img.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((.*)\)/,'$1');
img.style.backgroundImage = null
```

```html
 <img src="#" style="background:url('https://example.com/1.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;width:660px;height:330px;" class="demo-class">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //using javascript
    document.getElementById('imgTagId').src = 'https://example.com/1.jpg';

    //using jquery
    $('#imgTagId').attr('src','https://example.com/1.jpg');


//using style background-image
var imageUrl = $('#imgTagId').css("background-image");
document.getElementById('imgTagId').src = imageUrl.split(/"/)[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your image an tag an id then you can do something like this:
document.getElementById("imageid").src="../template/save.png"

for more information there is a similar question
[Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: the link you provided is complete different i want to grab the link from background inside style