# New to javascript, what kind of topic does this fit in?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, triggers

I'm learning HTML, CSS and Javascript after spending a few months creating test websites on Muse. I created this layout on it https://christianmdantas.000webhostapp.com/ but I've been trying to learn Javascript to not use muse anymore. I can't seem to find tutorials on how to do that. What topic does this layout fit in?

I've been trying to look for trigger changing images, something along got lines but can't seem to find it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Let's break down the problem. You want to [trigger a function when you click an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), and in that function, [change the source of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out codeacademy.com, It's free and has courses on CSS, HTML, Javascript, and more. Thats where I learned Python! You could also take a look at udemy but I believe it requires a subcription fee.