# Problems with displaying images from MongoDB using Multer on ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, multer-gridfs-storage

Basically to summarize my problem: I have some image to be displayed and it's displayed on localhost:5000 with status 200 where my Express server is running and when it comes to localhost:3000 i.e. my React Development Server, I made a request using Axios and it does give me gibberish and I don't know how to handle it at all.

React Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/filesuploaded/video_______82395d6a5af4e98fb8efca56f0ae3c1b_____.jpeg')
         .then(Response => console.log(Response))
         .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Express Code:

```
route.get('/:filename' , (req , res) => {
    GridFS.files.findOne({filename: req.params.filename} , (err , file) => {
        const readstream = GridFS.createReadStream(file.filename);
        readstream.pipe(res);
    })
});
```

Random Gibberish:

```
{data: "����..."
```

Comment: I think that it the base16 format of the image data..

Comment: @Mahendrasuthar then what's the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag

Comment: @Mahendrasuthar doesn't really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
So I played around more with the code and I had forgotten that this existed in my package.json of my client side and I have used it to full potential and rewrote my server side code without using multer anywhere.

**Package.json:**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000" //This helps React communicate with ExpressJS through ports.
```

**Server Side Config:**

```
const route           = require('express').Router();
const mongoose        = require('mongoose');
const GridFS          = require('gridfs-stream');

//Route for getting files
route.get('/file/:id' , (req , res) => {

  //Setting Up GridFS-Stream
  const db          = mongoose.connection.db;
  const MongoDriver = mongoose.mongo;
  const gfs         = new GridFS(db , MongoDriver);

  const readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
    _id: req.params.id,
  });

   //Reading to Response
   readstream.pipe(res);
});

module.exports = route;
```

**Front End Config:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Files extends Component {

//Render Method
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src = {window.location.pathname} alt = "something" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here the **window.location.pathname** will translate to **/file/:id** and send a **GET** request to ExpressJS, hence loading the image!