# choose the correct image from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created 4 **dropdown list**.

- First dropdownlist for select length of the module.
- Second dropdownlist for change the module color.
- Third dropdown list for select the part of the module.
- Fourth drop downlist we can add image on paticular part of module.

I tried to  add images but how can i add images particlular dropdownlist values.

> script code
>
> Module places for placing the selected images using array values

```
        var modulFront = {
    w_4: ["choose", "Front Modul 1", "Front Modul 2", "Front Modul 3", "Front Modul 4"],
    W_3: ["choose", "Front Modul 1", "Front Modul 2", "Front Modul 3", "Front Modul 4", "Front Modul 5"],

}



function changeModul(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("modulFront").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId in modulFront[value]) {
            catOptions += "<option>" + modulFront[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("modulFront").innerHTML = catOptions;
    }
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("modulBack").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId in modulRear[value]) {
            catOptions += "<option>" + modulRear[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("modulBack").innerHTML = catOptions;
    }
}
```

> different type of color modules

```
var picFront = {
    w4_Blue: ["w4_Blue.png"],

   w4_Red: ["w4_Red.png"],

   w4_Amber: ["w4_Amber.png"]
}
```

> using the section function called

```
function selection(){

if ($("#langd").val() && $("#bowcolor").val()) {

var langdVal = $("#langd").val();
var bowVal = $("#bowcolor").val();
var combineVal = langdVal+"_"+bowVal;
var inputDivHTML_Front = "";
var inputDivHTML_Rear = "";
var picF = picFront[combineVal];
var picB = picRear[combineVal];
```

> for in loop started from here

```
for(i in picF){
    inputDivHTML_Front += "<img class='showImg' src='"+"bage/"+picF[i]+"' alt='"+picF[i]+"'/>"; 
    inputDivHTML_Rear += "<img class='showImg' src='"+"bage/"+picB[i]+"' alt='"+picB[i]+"'/>"; 
}
$(".bageFront").html(inputDivHTML_Front);
$(".bageBack").html(inputDivHTML_Rear);
  }
}
```

> diffrent colors can choose on particular place on module by using array values

```
var colorCombFront = 
{

Blue: ["choose", "blue", "red", "green", "white", "amber"],

Red: ["choose", "blue", "red", "green", "white", "amber"],

Amber: ["choose", "blue", "red", "green", "white", "amber"]
 }
```

> change color

```
function changeColorComb(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("colorFront").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId in colorCombFront[value]) {
            catOptions += "<option>" + colorCombFront[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("colorFront").innerHTML = catOptions;
    }

  }
        </script>













    <div class="vrap">
    <section id="aside">
      <article>
        <form>
          <div>
```

> Dropdownlist 1 choosing length
>
> length

```
              <option value="">length</option>               
              <option value = "v1">4 moduler</option>
              <option value = "v2">5 moduler</option>

            </select>
            <script>
                $("#length").change(function() {
                      selection();
                });
            </script>
```

> Dropdownlist  for diffrent  colors to display  on the module

```
            <p>color</p>
            <select id = "bowcolor" name="bowcolor" style="float: left;" onChange="changeColorComb(this.value);">
              <!-- <option value="" disabled selected hidden></option> -->
              <option value="">color</option>               
              <option value = "Blue">Blue</option>
              <option value = "Red">Red</option>
              <option value = "Amber"></option>
            </select>
```

> change function for id bowcolor

```
            <script>
                $("#bowcolor").change(function() {
                        selection();

                     });
            </script>

          </div>
```

> change function for id colorFront

```
         <script>
           $('#colorFront').change(function(event){
            $('img').attr('src','flowers'+$(this).val()+'.png'); 
         });

          </script>
          <div>

            <p>Modul och color Front</p>
            <select id = "modulFront" name="modulFront" onchange="selectModulFront(this.value);">
              <option value=""></option>  
    </select>

            <select id = "colorFront" name="colorFront" onchange="selectColorFront(this.value);">
              <option value="blue"></option>
            </select>
          </div>

        </form>
      </article>
    </section>

    <section  id="main">
        <form class="flash">
```

> diffrent modules

```
        <div class="bageFront" name="bageFront">
                <img class="img-bar" src="bageFront.value" alt="bar
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would be great if could read about [How t create a Minimal, Reproducible and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) so it will be easier for everyone to understand your problem and think about a possible solution. Moreover you should add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve and if there is any error or just an understanding problem.

Comment: ok ty, how to display  the images from dropdown listThank you

Comment: Do you want to present the images **inside** the dropdown? Or put the urls in the dropdown (as text) and get it when, for example, user choose one of the options?

Comment: @Mosh Feu ....ya user choose one of the options

Comment: So, basically you are asking how to get the selected option's value?

Comment: when i sect first dropdown list i can select  diffrent size of modules.It's going to display module image on right side.                                                                   When i select  second dropdown list i can change the color of module.

Comment: @Mosh Feu..how to set the images when i select options

Comment: Set the img's src attribute? You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722422/863110