# Programatically modify an <img> url to addend with "?example-text=50" and prefix with "<some text>"

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, edit

A beginner back end developer here.

I am basically trying to implement these instructions on my website forum so that my images aren't so huge for thumbnails slowing things down hugely: https://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-resize-images-on-server-side/

I am on the second part.

Basically I have some code like this:

```
<a class="IndexImage" href="/forum/discussion/55/design-flaw-001-give-up"><img src="/forum/uploads/editor/dm/idnutwgmgaik.jpg" class="IndexImage"></a>
```

But I need the image src to change to

```
<img src="<?php loadImage('/forum/uploads/editor/dm/idnutwgmgaik.jpg', 50, 50) ?>"
```

I'm not sure if this would be possible with Javascript, or if at all? The logic I want to implement is basically iff .IndexImage img ---> then, prefix ~~`<?php loadImage('`~~ to img source and append ~~`', 50, 50) ?>`~~

It could be really easy, it could be impossible. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you. I hope the question is very clear.

I have found this page explaining how you can change the src to something preset, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag#_=_) , but I am trying to dynamically modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the source with javascript you can use jquery and [$.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) `.attr('src','NEW SOURCE GOES HERE')` https://jsfiddle.net/uv58rkb6/

Why would you want to input a php function as the `source` to an image?

`<img src="<?php loadImage('/forum/uploads/editor/dm/idnutwgmgaik.jpg', 50, 50) ?>"`

`loadImage()` is a php function that (based on the parameters) builds an html element from the inputs including height/width, you cannot edit the height or width within the `src` attribute. You would end up with invalid html something like:

`<img src="<img src="idnutwgmgaik.jpg" width="50" height="50">">`

Also you cannot call the `loadImage()` php function after the page has loaded. PHP runs once when the page loads. If you want to dynamically change your images on the backend using PHP use jquery's AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadimage.php",
    success: function(data) {
          //return the output of loadimage.php in the data callback
          $("#imageID").attr("src", data);
    }

});
```