# Generating HTML with strings

Tags: javascript, string-building

I am trying to add an image into HTML. Using the following works:

```
<img id="image1" src="http://image.jpg" alt=" " width="300" height="300" />
```

All i want to do is replace the http with a variable so I can call in the website rather than have it be physically inline:

```
<img id="image1" src=URL alt=" " width="300" height="300" />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Leave the src empty, and then in JS, get a reference to the image using `id`, then simply set `src` to what you need.

Comment: where your variable will come from? javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to dynamically change your src attribute, here is how to do it :

```js
// we selct the element to change in a variable
var el = document.getElementById("image1");

// we define a new image
var new_url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT744-ntmnfTx78ZjYUG9t_SkW-M2JmpJaUr6iYlyhaVzkXT9q2';

// we set the new image
el.setAttribute("src",new_url);
```

```html
<img id="image1" src="http://image.jpg" alt="nothing to show" width="300" height="300" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the img and set the src:

```
document.getElementById('image1').src='http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html don't set the image source, but still have the img element in the DOM. I.e:

`<img id="image1" alt=" " width="300" height="300" />`

In your  javascript (which should be loaded in the bottom of your `<body>` tag in your html) you do as follows:

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById('image1');

img1.src = "/some/url/or/file-path/here.jpg"
```