# How to pull in an image from an object by manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, image, object, dom

I'm building a small JavaScript game where you pick a random card and it displays the card's title, image and description. The cards are objects and I am able to change the title and description BUT NOT THE IMAGE. You can see it here https://angry-albattani-3bae62.netlify.com/. Thank you very much for any help!

```
 <div class="container">

      <h2 id="tarotTitle">Tarot Card</h2>

      <img id="image" src="highPriestess.jpg" alt="A picture of a Tarot Card">

      <p id="tarotMeaning">Lorem, ipsum dolor</p>

    </div>
```

app.js

```
const pullCard = document.getElementById("pullCard");
const tarotTitle = document.getElementById("tarotTitle");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const tarotMeaning = document.getElementById("tarotMeaning");

// random number function
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const tarotCards = [
  {
    cardName: "High Priestess",
    image: "highPriestess.jpg",
    description: "I am a high priestess"
  },
  {
    cardName: "the Magician",
    image: "theMagician.jpg",
    description: "I am a magician"
  },
  {
    cardName: "The Empress",
    image: "theEmpress.jpg",
    description: "I am an Empress"
  }
];

pullCard.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const currentCard = getRandomInt(3);
  // Card title
  tarotTitle.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].cardName;
  // Card image
  image.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].image;
  // Card Description
  tarotMeaning.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].description;
});
```

Comment: Similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image.src instead of image.innerHTML. You are using innerHTML which changes text of your image element, but you need to change your image src for the image to locate the source

```js
const pullCard = document.getElementById("pullCard");
const tarotTitle = document.getElementById("tarotTitle");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const tarotMeaning = document.getElementById("tarotMeaning");

// random number function
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const tarotCards = [
  {
    cardName: "High Priestess",
    image: "highPriestess.jpg",
    description: "I am a high priestess"
  },
  {
    cardName: "the Magician",
    image: "theMagician.jpg",
    description: "I am a magician"
  },
  {
    cardName: "The Empress",
    image: "theEmpress.jpg",
    description: "I am an Empress"
  }
];

pullCard.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const currentCard = getRandomInt(3);
  // Card title
  tarotTitle.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].cardName;
  // Card image
  image.src = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].image;
  // Card Description
  tarotMeaning.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].description;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That did it!

Answer (score 1):

To change the image you need to update the [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src) attribute of the [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), not its `innerHTML` like:

```
// Card image
image.src = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].image;
```

Demo:

```js
const pullCard = document.getElementById("pullCard");
const tarotTitle = document.getElementById("tarotTitle");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const tarotMeaning = document.getElementById("tarotMeaning");

// random number function
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const tarotCards = [{
    cardName: "High Priestess",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/200",
    description: "I am a high priestess"
  },
  {
    cardName: "the Magician",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/id/1009/300/200",
    description: "I am a magician"
  },
  {
    cardName: "The Empress",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200",
    description: "I am an Empress"
  }
];

pullCard.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const currentCard = getRandomInt(3);
  // Card title
  tarotTitle.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].cardName;
  // Card image
  image.src = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].image;
  // Card Description
  tarotMeaning.innerHTML = tarotCards[`${currentCard}`].description;
});
```

```html
<button id="pullCard">Pull Card</button>
<div class="container">
  <h2 id="tarotTitle">Tarot Card</h2>
  <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/200" alt="A picture of a Tarot Card">
  <p id="tarotMeaning">Lorem, ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) to help future users too. Thanks!