# slideshow not working but also not showing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to make a slideshow with HTML and JavaScript but it's not working and i'm getting no error. I have 2 scripts... one to put the images into the html and the other to make it a slideshow. This is JavaScript to show show the images:

```js
var folder = "uploads/";
var img = "<img src='";
var imgStyle = "style='width:100%'";
var imgClass = "class='slide'";
$.ajax({
  url : folder,
  success : function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val){
      if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
        $( "#slideshow" ).append( img + folder + val + "'" + imgClass + imgStyle + ">");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The above works fine but the slideshow is the problem. With out the slideshow.js file the images show up, but once i run the slideshow javascript it makes everything invisible. Here is the code from the slideshow.js file:

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow .slide'),
  currentSlide = 0,
  firstBtn = document.getElementById('one'),
  secondBtn = document.getElementById('two'),
  thirdBtn = document.getElementById('three');

function getAllSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  elem = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
  do {
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
    if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
  } while (elem = elem.nextSibling)
  return sibs;
}

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide active';
};

firstBtn.onclick = function() {
  var slide = getAllSiblings(slides[0]);
  slide.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  });
  slides[0].className = 'slide active';
  var result = getAllSiblings(this);
  result.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  })
  this.classList.add('active');

};
secondBtn.onclick = function() {
  var slide = getAllSiblings(slides[1]);
  slide.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  });
  slides[1].className = 'slide active';
  var result = getAllSiblings(this);
  result.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  })
  this.classList.add('active');

};
thirdBtn.onclick = function() {
  var slide = getAllSiblings(slides[2]);
  slide.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  });
  slides[2].className = 'slide active';
  var result = getAllSiblings(this);
  result.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
  })
  this.classList.add('active');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index2.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/display.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
  <title>Test Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slideshow">

  </div>
  <div class="controllers">
    <span id='one' class='active'></span>
    <span id='two'></span>
    <span id='three'></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a code pen for the display: https://codepen.io/ksaeidnia0/pen/BaozNzP

Here is a code pen for the slideshow: https://codepen.io/ksaeidnia0/pen/ZEbOGWz

Comment: **Nothing shows up**?? What does that mean? Did the images load from your WebAPI Call?

Comment: Thank you, I will clarify more in the question.

Comment: can you make an example here that we can run and test?

Comment: Do you mean like a codepen or something

Comment: Sure, anything that can provide a minimal complete example of the issue you are having

Comment: alright, i'll see if i can set one up

Comment: Just realized, you won't be able to see the images anyway, cause they are received from a local storage. But the codepens are at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You can input any example images from the internet, just copy the image URL into the image tag src and it will pull it from anywhere

Comment: Will do, also should i move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Ok, i have updated the codepens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using built-in slideshow from bootstrap, click [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) for more info. A code sample is below. It is way simpler and you can have captions as well.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Remember to import bootstrap by this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or those if you want JavaScript and others

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also change the image source by Javascript by something like

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "TheImage";
```

More info press [here - w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp), [here - w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb) and [here - stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: would this allow me to use java script to import the images?

Comment: Yes, I have put the answer in my answer. Or press here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp