# Replacing an image element's src attribute value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the image source, but only if the image corresponds to the existing class "overview-icon--downtime". Then there's another class, "overview-icon--degraded", which I want to replace it with (or simply putting an image address, which might prove easier).

To be replaced:

```
<div class="page__overview">
<img class="page__overview-icon overview-icon--downtime" src="downtime_large.png">
</div>
```

To be replaced with:

```
<div class="page__overview">
<img class="page__overview-icon page__overview-icon--degraded" src="degraded_large.png">
</div>
```

I was thinking of this, but I'm not sure I'm heading in the right direction.

```
document.querySelector(".page__overview-icon overview-icon--downtime").setAttribute("img", "page__overview-icon page__overview-icon--degraded");
```

The image loads with the page, so I'll also need to use the AJAX at the end.

Any ideas here please? Thanks a lot in advance! :3

Comment: You have the same two classes in your text; "overview-icon--downtime"

Comment: Did you mean to set the `img` attribute, or the `class` attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: If you want to change the `src` instead, [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11722400/215552)

Comment: Sorry for the double downtime and thanks for pointing this out @HereticMonkey!

Not sure what would be better solution. If I should replace only the img or class, as they overlap.

Comment: "Better" sounds like an opinion, something that we don't really do on Stack Overflow. Facts and experience, sure, but how are we to determine which is better for you in your situation, in the short and long term. Too many variables.

Answer (score -1):

You are heading in the right direction.

Attributes are the things inside of the tags. In this instance, "class" and "src" are attributes of the img element.

document.querySelector will select the img element, you then need to call setAttribute('class', *new class value*), and setAttribute('src', *new src value*)

Comment: Setting the `class` attribute is a poor way of updating the classes applied to an element. Use modern APIs like the `classList` `DOMTokenList` API instead, as it says in the duplicate.

Comment: You are correct, but I am attempting to give the user a better understanding of attributes as a concept.