# How can I write the content of a variable in image src while using document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have the following code

```
document.write("<img src=./", i, ".png width='100px' height='100px'>");
document.write("<img src=./", x, ".png width='100px' height='100px'>");
document.write("<img src=./", y, ".png width='100px' height='100px'>");`
```

and I want to use the `src` in `getElementById(myImg).InnerHTML`.

I tried this

```
document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML.src = "./", i, ".png width='100px' height='100px'>";
```

But It's not working

What is the proper way to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `src`, not `InnerHTML.src`. You can see the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag).
and you need to set the `width` `height` with style

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src=`./${i}.png`;
document.getElementById("myImg").style.width="100px";
document.getElementById("myImg").style.height="100px";
```

Answer (score -1):

You've syntax errors in your code.

Try this

```js
const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
const i = 'some_string_or_number'
 
img.src = "./"+i+".png";
img.width='100px';
img.height='100px';
```